# sed && svn problem

Tags: svn, sed

i have an svn working copy which i executed the following command in

> find ./source * -type f -exec sed "s/@version 0.5.3/@version 0.5.4/" -i {} \;

the files are all updated but svn doesn't recognize any change when executing one of theese

> svn status ./source
>
> svn diff ./source
>
> svn commit ./source

i also tried to write a script which shpould check the $? from sed and it it's ok the "touch" the file to update it's mdate but sed seems to always return 0 -.-

what can i do now? -.-

Comment: I don't know of a sed implementation that has a `-I` option. You might have intended the `-i` option. Is this really the command you ran?

Comment: sorry it was -i, sed itssef is working as i said...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies in your usage of `find`:

```
find dir1 -type f
```

Will match all files in the directory structure, including those inside the `.svn` directories. The files in `.svn` are those used to perform the `svn diff` against. So, in essence, you have modified all copies of the files in the tree, not just the working copies.

Try this syntax:

```
find ./source * -type f ! -path '*/.svn/*' -exec sed "s/@version 0.5.3/@version 0.5.4/" -I {} \;
```

Comment: i don't need backups, all is in svn...

Comment: @zolex You misunderstand. All the files in `*/.svn/text-base/` are backups of the files on the subversion server. DO NOT MODIFY THEM.

Comment: btw, need to escape the dots on the version regex as it will find other things like 0x523

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turned out I was updating a symlinc link to the real file. I used sed in-place update. Interestingly, this turns a symbolic link to a regular file. Then svn was not happy because the "object" type was changed of course.

Here is how a symbolic link is changed to a regular file:

```
user@host>ls -l txt*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 90 Feb 28  2020 txtfile
lrwxrwxrwx 1 user user 7 Aug  5 11:07 txtln -> txtfile
user@host>sed -i "s/hello/mello/" txtln
user@host>ls -l txt*
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 90 Feb 28  2020 txtfile
-rw-rw-r-- 1 user user 90 Aug  5 11:08 txtln
user@host>
```